# How to invert a Map<String, ArrayList<String>> in Java?

Tags: java, java-7

I have a map with `"task(s)": ["epochdate1", "epochdate2"]` how can I reverse (invert) this map?

For example

```
task_1 => [date1, date2, date3, date5]
task_2 => [date4, date5]
task_3 => [date2, date3, date5]
task_4 => [date4, date5]
```

when reversed it will be

```
date1 => [task_1]
date2 => [task_1, task_3]
date3 => [task_1, task_3]
date4 => [task_2, task_4]
date5 => [task_1, task_2, task_3, task_4]
```

Code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> t1List = new ArrayList<String>();
    t1List.add("date1");
    t1List.add("date2");
    t1List.add("date3");
    t1List.add("date5");
    ArrayList<String> t2List = new ArrayList<String>();
    t2List.add("date4");
    t2List.add("date5");
    ArrayList<String> t3List = new ArrayList<String>();
    t3List.add("date2");
    t3List.add("date3");
    t3List.add("date5");
    ArrayList<String> t4List = new ArrayList<String>();
    t4List.add("date4");
    t4List.add("date5");
    myMap.put("task_1", t1List);
    myMap.put("task_2", t2List);
    myMap.put("task_3", t3List);
    myMap.put("task_4", t4List);
    
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> reversedMap = Test.getReversedMap(myMap);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement it:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> getReversedMap(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap){
      Map<String, ArrayList<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
      for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
          for(String val : myMap.get(key)){
              if(!result.containsKey(val)){
                  result.put(val, new ArrayList());
              }
              result.get(val).add(key);
          }
      }
      return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no short cuts. You have to iterate over the entrySet of the original map, and for each date value you find, put a new entry in the new map with the matching task as the first value, or add the task to the list of an existing entry if the date is already in the new map.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Guava for this. Try something like:

```
Map<K, V> map = ...;
ListMultimap<V, K> inverse = Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map), 
ArrayListMultimap.<V,K>create());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Java 8+ using streams:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> invertedMap = myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

## Step-by-step breakdown

1. Convert the map to a stream of entries

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>>
   myMap.entrySet().stream()
   ```
2. Split apart each entry into a separate item per item in the value list

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>>
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
   ```
3. Group the entries into a new map, with keys equal to the previous values, and values containing a list of each original key mapped to that value.

   ```java
   // Map<String, List<String>>
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           Map.Entry::getValue,
           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
   ```